# Is the Hadamard Product a continuous mapping?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ are $n \times m$ matrices. Letting
$$ f : \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} $$
where
$$ f(\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}) := \mathbf{A} \odot \mathbf{B} $$
with $\odot$ denoting the Hadamard/element-wise product of the matrices.

Is $f$ a continuous mapping on its domain?

---

Edit: Adding some more details here as I am not very familiar with the concepts of bilinear or polynomial maps.

From elementary real analysis, we know that a vector-valued mapping
$$ f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^K $$
is continuous at $\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ iff each component is continuous, so if $f(\mathbf{p}) = (f_1(\mathbf{p}), f_2(\mathbf{p}), \dots, f_K(\mathbf{p}))$, then we have
$$ \forall k=1,\dots, K, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 s.t. 0 < ||\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}|| < \delta \implies ||f(\mathbf{x}), f(\mathbf{p}))|| < \epsilon $$

One way of approaching this question (which I am not sure is entirely correct), is to think of the mapping of matrices
$$ f: \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} $$
as a giant vector-valued mapping
$$ f : \mathbb{R}^{2nm} \to \mathbb{R}^{nm} $$
where we take the two $n\times m$ matrices, and stack them into a single vector of dimension $2nm$. We may then apply the earlier result of continuity in each component implies continuity of the mapping. Would this approach be correct?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: Hint: it is bilinear.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the comment, though I'm not sure what else I could've added in the question.

Regarding your hint, my understanding is that a bilinear form is some mapping of the form $f : \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(x, y) = x^T A y$ for some $n \times m$ matrix $A$. However since the Hadamard product is an element-wise mapping between two matrices, would you mind explaining how it is a bilinear form?

Comment: 1) what you should add is indicated in the link. 2) It is not a bilinear *form* but it is [bilinear](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map). On finite dimensional spaces, all multilinear maps are continuous.

Comment: 3) Your edit is fine except that $(nm)^2$ should be replaced with $2nm.$ It is essentially the same as @NicolasGuès' answer below, which he shouldn't have restricted to square matrices.

Answer (score 2):

The Hadamard product is continuous in each coordinate, in the sense that $M_n \times M_n \xrightarrow{\odot} M_n \xrightarrow{(-)_{ij}} \mathbb R$ is continuous (because it is a polynomial map, seeing $M_n(\mathbb R)$ as $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ !). This implies that the Hadamard product is continuous.

Comment: I was meaning it is continuous in each target coordinate, in the sense that the compositions $M_n \times M_n \to M_n \xrightarrow{(-)_{ij}} \mathbb R$ are continuous.

Comment: Oh well! please edit your answer to both include this and justify this continuity of each component. (Or simply delete the answer, because we are not supposed to answer such a "no-effort question".)

Comment: Did it. Sorry for the misleading answer.